# Excel checkbox value property can't be set in rare occasions

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a script which changes the checkstate of two checkboxes in an excel sheet. The full procedure is:

1. Opening an Excel template file
2. Filling out some data, one of that steps is using the sub below
3. Saving the file at a specific location

The file template therefore is always the same. On some occasions (<5% of the time), the routine fails in the sub below in the first of the two lines `sh.ControlFormat.Value = -4146` with an error

```
Microsoft Excel: Die Value-Eigenschaft des CheckBox-Objektes kann nicht festgelegt werden.
```

which probably is the translation of the English error message

```
Unable to Set the Value property of the CheckBox Class
```

If that happens, you can close the file, start the exact same routine again and it so far for me has always worked then. Since I am running through all shapes, checking their type, checking their form-control-type and then checking the individual name, I am unsure how this is still failing since the file is obviously open, accessible and the correct form-control-element has been found.

Any idea how to mitigate this? I'd be happy with any insight what might cause such an error in order to find a way around it. Ideally something working better than simply detecting it and telling the user that *something has gone wrong, please close excel and try again*.

```
Sub modify_ci(oExcel, inp_cib)
    
    Set sheet = oExcel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    For Each sh in sheet.Shapes
        If sh.Type = 8 Then ' 8 => msoFormControl
            If sh.FormControlType = 1 Then ' 1 => xlCheckBox
                If(sh.Name = "chkbox_ci_yes") Then
                    If(inp_cib = "true") Then
                        sh.ControlFormat.Value = 1
                    Else
                        sh.ControlFormat.Value = -4146
                    End If
                ElseIf(sh.Name = "chkbox_ci_no") Then
                    If(inp_cib = "false") Then
                        sh.ControlFormat.Value = 1
                    Else
                        sh.ControlFormat.Value = -4146
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried setting it to `False` instead of `-4146`?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Generally both works, any idea why that could make a difference? Since it happens so rarely it is difficult to validate whether this solves the issue

Comment: Sadly not but i remember sometimes Excel don't like one kind of value while accepting another one that should have the same valence. Then again: it happened to me rarely so i can't recall a specific case. Therefore i just posted a comment hoping it could have helped, because right now i don't have a sure answer.